# What is regularexpression to allow specific characters in php

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework

i want to allow only characters X,N,-,(Space) to string which user inputs.

Ex : XXXX-NNNNN XXXXXX-NNNN is valid string but
Ex   XXXx-1NNN XXXX-NNNN is not valid string.

I have found so many regexp for that but didn't find helpful solution

I want this solution in zend form

Comment: Please consider taking a look at the [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match("/^[XN -]+$/", $string);
```